# Resize image to fit into LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to dynamically add some images to a LinearLayout based on what the user selects but I cannot figure out how to resize the images before adding them.  I have tried the `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods but it seems to do nothing.  I would like to set them to a certain dp.

Thanks to anyone looking at this.

```
 ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

image.setLayoutParams(params);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.iconLayout);
layout.addView(image, cart.size()-1, params);
```

Comment: Uset FitXY instead of center

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER
```

What it is doing is that it will scale your image but it will only fit on either x or y axis.

from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER):

```
Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, 
but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least 
one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.
```

**solution:**

You can use the `ImageView.ScaleType.FILL` to scale your image in x and y axis depends on the **height** and **width** of your `ImageView`.

```
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FILL);
```

Comment: It does not like `FILL` and causes an error.  The reason (although it must not be correct) is because I wanted it to be centered, and when the next one is added, it would slide over and they would both be centered, and so on.  I must be completely off on my thinking.

Comment: @WeVie can you post an image what it looks like. with `CENTER`

Comment: Using `CENTER` was adding it to the center but it was spilling out of the layout dimensions and covering up a textview I have above it.  Using `FIT_CENTER` seems to force it to fit into the layout without distorting the image.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I figured it out thanks to being steered in the correct direction.  I was able to use `FIT_CENTER` and that done it.